# Is There A Way To Calculate Data In Task Manager?

Tags: memory, task-manager, process, utilization

Something takes a lot of RAM and i want to know what. I have list of running processes and need to know the sum of all of them because "In Use" does not help me to determine what takes most RAM:

[image]

I several times had this "leak" but everybody told me it is not leak and system uses that much memory. According to screenshot thsi is not true. Is there a way to copy this data to Excel and do the calculations there? Or any other way which allwos me to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give Windows Process Explorer a try.  It has some agregating functions, and allows you to see the process ownership tree.

It's published my Microsoft, and is available for download [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)

*UPDATE:* Apparently Process Explorer can't aggregate memory usage.

Comment: How do i display memory amount each process takes? What do i select here? http://i.imgur.com/oVcoY.png

Comment: I guess I was mistaken.  I just tried to do the aggregate memory, and was unable to.